# Java Web App - error 404 when trying to run JSP file (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, jsp, web, intellij-idea, servlets

When I am trying to run JSP file (rightclick on filename and Run in IntelliJ) I am getting
[404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NmRy.png)

My JSP code:

```
`<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sites.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>Add</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="button.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h1>Add Company</h1><br>
</form>
    <br><br>
    <p>fill the form below to add company:</p>
    <form action="add" method="post">
        <table style="width:80%">
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
            <tr>
                <td>Register Number</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="register_number" /></td>
        </table><br>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="buttonbtn"/></td></tr></table>
    </form>
    <br><br>
    <table>
        <tr><td><a href="/miniCRM/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/main.html" class=buttonbtn>Main Page</a></td></tr></table>
</div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Servlet:

```
`package com.example.minicrm.controller;
import com.example.minicrm.dao.CompanyDao;
import com.example.minicrm.model.Company;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class UserServlet
 */

@WebServlet(name = "add")
public class AddCompanyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final CompanyDao CompanyDao = new CompanyDao();
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AddCompanyServlet() {
        super();
        System.out.println("ok");

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/AddCompany.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String register_number = request.getParameter("register_number");

        Company company = new Company();
        company.setName(name);
        company.setRegister_number(register_number);

        try {
            CompanyDao.addCompany(company);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/AddCompany.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

}
`
```

POM.xml:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>miniCRM</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>miniCRM</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.84</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>`
```

Adding dependencies:

```
 `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.84</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>`
```

didn't help.

I am trying to run it on localhost. Can't run it with mvn clean-spring boot run (don't have such an option).

I will be thankfull for all suggestions.

Comment: Which problem are you trying to ask about?

Comment: I am trying to render my JSP, but instead I got 404, what do I do wrong?

Comment: Did you read the error message? The server didn't find the requested page.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of WEB-INF are not directly requestable by clients. That's where your class files, your property files, and who knows what else go. Move the file outside of there.